# Difference of multipage tiff

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have to calculate the difference of two images. Currently I do this with [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). The following code works well for jpg or single page tiffs:

```
convert fileA.jpg fileB.jpg -compose -Difference -composite -colorspace gray -format '%[fx:mean]' info:
```

When I edit a multipage tiff on the second page and use command above with modified and unmodified tiff, I get the same result like compare fileA with itself, so I think that imagemagick compares page 1 with page 2 of fileA.

Actual I split the multipage images into single image files and compare page by page, but this is slow!

---

**Windows:**

```
...>magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-11 Q16 x64 2018-08-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

**Ubuntu 14.04**

```
....# convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-07-10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

---

How can I get a percentage difference of the two compared tiffs fast? Maybe there is a way with imagemagick or another with bash/java/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by appending all the pages of each TIFF image together before doing the composite in Imagemagick. For example with a 4 page test tiff that I made, where the second page has been blurred:

```
convert \( test1.tif +adjoin -append \) \( test2.tif +adjoin -append \) -compose difference -composite -colorspace gray -format '%[fx:mean]\n' info:

0.00847632
```

You can also do that with -layers composite and get the difference for each page.

```
convert test1.tif +adjoin null: test2.tif +adjoin -compose difference -layers composite -colorspace gray -format '%[fx:mean]\n' info:


0
0.0324311
0
0
```

Comment: I just get 'convert: unrecognized compose operator `-layers' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1143.' with my windows machine.Tested this @ubuntu 14.04 and it works.

What would be nice, since I'm testing at a windows machine, a command that works on both ubuntu and windows :-)

Comment: It is not possible to have one command for both Unix and Windows. Syntax is different for Window than for Unix systems. For Windows remove the \ before the parenthesis, but be sure to leave the space between the parentheses and the text. Windows may need double quotes as well. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/. If you are using IM 7 rather than IM 6, then replace convert with magick. See https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli